# External Image Link from Parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I created a report in SSRS. I would like to add a image to report as External. I inserted a link ("http://www.aa.com/Images/a.jpg") to image object. It is working well. But I change the link (= Parameters!ImagePath.Value + "/a.jpg") in Image value. The Parameters!ImagePath.Value is "http://www.aa.com/Images". It is not working. How can I resolve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To concatenate Strings in Reporting Services, you must use the "&" operator. In your case, it will be:

```
=Parameters!ImagePath.Value & "/a.jpg"
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

It may seem weird, but tried to convert this parameter to a string? It's happened to me something of the genre.

```
CSTR(Parameters!ImagePath.value)+"/a.jpg"
```

Another possible solution is to change the "**External**" to "**Embedded**" image.